# Inserting a JavaScript resource into a Liferay Portlet

Tags: java, include, liferay, portlet, jstree

I would like to use [jsTree](http://www.jstree.com/) inside of my Liferay portlet, but everytime the script gets executed I get an error:

> TypeError: treeContainer.jstree is not a function @ localhost:8080/web/guest/home:14

I understand that it doesn't have the JS file available for use, so I've tried these two approaches, but niether of them works.

**First:** Include it directly by adding

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
```

into the JSP. Although I can see it being "linked" in my IDE, after building and deploying it's unavailable (duh).

**Second:** Editing it in the `liferay-portlet.xml` like this:

```
<portlet>
    <portlet-name>myPortlet</portlet-name>
    <instanceable>false</instanceable>
    <!-- other mappings here -->
    <header-portlet-javascript>my/resource/folder/myPortlet/jquery.jstree.js
    </header-portlet-javascript>
</portlet>
```

But even if I edit it in like this I get an 404 in the browser console.

Function used in the JSP:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".tree-search").click(function(){

    treeContainer = $(this).siblings('.tree-container');

    // correct data is taken from ${jsonFake}
    treeContainer.jstree({
        "plugins":["themes","html_data","ui"], "json_data": { data: ${jsonFake}}
    });

    treeContainer.show();
    treeContainer.animate({
        opacity: "1"
    }, 750);

});
</script>
```

What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: can you make sure your js path starts after docroot folder? For Example if js is at path docroot/js/abc.js and your js-path should be /js/abc.js

Comment: well in standalone/deployments I choose the WAR folder for my module and then the path is "WEB-INF/js/jquery.jstree.js" so I've put that into my liferay-portlet.xml but it doesn't work.. I'll try to play around with it a bit more..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems like path issue:

Create a folder named js inside docroot and put this file there.
Add script src like:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='/js/jquery.jstree.js'></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

add the js file in portal_normal.vm file in your current theme .like

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.jstree.js"></script>
```